# Android Studio error: too many constants

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My project has many Strings in Java classes and many xml files. I'm using Multidex for this, but when I'm trying to build an APK I get this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingAdapters10Rc5Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidDatabindingLibrary10Rc5Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\WoW17\WoW17\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\xxx\test\R.java
Error:(12127, 25) error: too many constants
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3 mins 5.842 secs
Information:2 errors
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.66"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

I used eclipse before, but I couldn't multidex with it, so that's why I switched over to using Android Studio. I have  35000 Strings, also xml and Java files. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: *35k strings*? declared in `strings.xml`?

Comment: yes with x7 language support

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have not thrown in the JAVA_HOME variable, here is a guide to do it:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/